# The origin of "break of day"

Tags: phrase-origin

I was quite surprised to know that "break of day" actually means "dawn", that is, the beginning of the day.

But, the phrase "break of day" sounds much more like the end of the day, not the beginning of it. So, I'm quite interested in the origin of it.

Comment: You're completely mistaken in supposing ***break*** "sounds much more like the end of the day". A snooker player starts a new game by ***breaking off***, and disease epidemics, for example, start by ***breaking out***. Granted, when a *fever breaks,* that means it's *ended*, but the word ***break*** itself simply implies a *significant change* in such contexts, not particularly a beginning or an end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Daybreak](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=daybreak&searchmode=none)  (n.) is  quite an old expression:

> - 1520s, from day + break (n.).

[Break](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=break&allowed_in_frame=0):

> - Meaning "to disclose" is from early 13c.

(Etymonline)

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=break%20of%20day%2Cdaybreak&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbreak%20of%20day%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdaybreak%3B%2Cc0) shows that both expressions, *daybreak and break of day*,  have been used from the 16th century.

[At the crack of dawn](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/at+the+crack+of+dawn)  is a similar expression:

> - Fig. at the earliest light of the day. Jane was always awake at the crack of dawn. The birds start singing at the break of dawn.
>     (McGraw-Hill Dictionary)